# Procedure or function which was not supplied Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of items on a webpage that would like to let the user clicking a button to approve or reject item or items on the list. However I get this error message 'Procedure or function 'requisition_sp_setstatus0' expects parameter '@reqNumber', which was not supplied.' at this line command.ExecuteNonQuery(). Additionally I would like to add to the controller that if a checkbox is not selected gives the user this error message; Please select an item

Controller

```
public ActionResult Approve(Requisition requisition,string reqNumber) 
{
    IssueDAO dbObj = new IssueDAO(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TWCL_OPERATIONSConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    dbObj.SetRequisitionStatus0(reqNumber);
    ViewBag.Message = "Approval Successful!";
    return RedirectToAction("RequisitionList","Requisition");
}
```

Method

```
public void SetRequisitionStatus0(string reqNumber)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandText = "requisition_sp_setstatus0";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@reqNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=reqNumber;
    command.Parameters.Add("@approve_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
    using (command.Connection = connection)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Id guess the string req number is null. Otherwise it looks ok. No comment on the checkbox

Comment: yes it is null. why no comment on the checkbox issue

Comment: You must add a value to a parameter even if the value is `DbNull.Value` or else you will get that error.

Comment: Probably your sp doesn't accept a null value on that parameter. I have no good answer on the checkbox

Comment: where should I add the value

Comment: @user3532232, ok give me what you have maybe it will give me a hint

Comment: Or you can apply a default in the stored procedure. You may want [to read this](https://contrivedexample.com/2016/10/22/input-output-and-inputoutput-sqlparameter-behavior-explained/)

Comment: can someone assist me with this question please.

Comment: Can you explain `Requisition` model content (as you're mentioning selected checkbox) and how you passing `reqNumber` value to controller method (i.e. view page code)? If `reqNumber` is null then check view page part where that value should be passed (either using AJAX or form submit).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932758/use-checkbox-to-approve-list-of-items-and-update-database?noredirect=1#comment82835907_47932758 updated question